# How can I determine if $T$ is diagonalizable with this associated matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

Let be $V$ a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ with dimension 4. Let be $T$ a lineal operator in $V$. In case that a base $\mathcal{B}$ of $V$ exists, such that the associated matrix of $T$ relative to the basis $\mathcal{B}$ is:
$$
\left [ T \right ]_{\mathcal{B}}=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & a & 0 & 0\\ 
0 & 1 & b & 0\\ 
0 & 0 & 1 & c\\ 
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
with $a^{2}+b^{2}+c^{2} \neq 0$, determine if T is diagonalizable.

With this information, what I can deduce is this:

If $\mathcal{B}=\left \{ x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}  \right \}$ then:

\begin{align*}
T(x_{1})&=x_{1}+0x_{2}+0x_{3}+0x_{4}\\
T(x_{2})&=ax_{1}+x_{2}+0x_{3}+0x_{4}\\
T(x_{3})&=0x_{1}+bx_{2}+x_{3}+0x_{4}\\
T(x_{4})&=0x_{1}+0x_{2}+cx_{3}+x_{4}\\
\end{align*}

So, If I'm correct, just $x_{1}$ is a eigenvector and $\Rightarrow$ T is not diagonizable. *Am I in th correct? If I'm not, then how can I determine if T is diagonizable or not?*

I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not correct. You only know for *certain* that $e_1$ is an eigenvector. If $b  = 0$, then $e_3$ is an eigenvector as well, and similarly for $a$ and $c$.

What you **can** do is this:

Without loss of generality, assume $a \ne 0$. Then for the vector $e_2$, we have
$$
T(e_2) = a e_1 + e_2
$$
so
$$
(T-I) e_2 = ae_1.
$$
Further,
$$
(T-I) e_1 = 0
$$
So $e_2$ is a generalized eigenvector for the eigenvalue $1$ , so it's impossible for $T$ to have a basis of (true) eigenvectors.

[I'm using the following here: if $T$ is diagonalizable, then there are no generalized eigenvectors of $T$, i.e., there's no $c \ne 0$, $k > 1$ and $v$ such that $(T-cI)^k (v) = 0$, but $(T-cI)^{k-1}(v) \ne =0$. That's a small theorem that requires proof, which I leave to you. A vector $v$ with this property is called "generalized eigenvector for $c$".]

Answer (score 0):

For a matrix to be diagonalizable the geometric multiplicity of every eigenvalue should be less than or equal to the algebraic multiplicity